# Passport authentication without using a templating engine

Tags: angular, express, oauth, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am trying to use Passport authentication using Google strategy. I can get the app authenticated via google but after it comes back to my express server I want to pass it on to a client side page along with the profile data.

Which means essentially I don't want to use a templating engine.

So once my google call back hits successredirect here I need to redirect to my client side **with the data**

```
router.route('/google/callback')
.get(passport.authenticate('google', {
    successRedirect: '/users/',
    failure: '/error/'
}));
```

I couldn't find any repos that do this without a templating engine so far. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you have more details? This sounds easy. Can you explain what you mean by "after it comes back"? What is "it"? Is the "app" a phone app or a web app? What is the client? After a successful authentication Google will simply call your callback. You can do whatever you like.  My standard call back is "/google/redirect"  and we do it like this:  router.get('/google/redirect',passport.authenticate('google'),(req,res) => {
    // Handle with passport
    //console.log(req.user);
    res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');
})

Comment: It's a web app. As of now the client is simple HTML with jQuery. So the problem is //console.log(req.user); res.redirect('/admin/dashboard') here /admin/dashboard looks for a server side route with right? So how do I make is redirect to a client side route instead?

Comment: The redirects are always on the client side. For example, when I test I redirect to "http:://localhost/admin/dashboard". The res.redirect is telling the client which URL to go to next relative to the client. Where do you want your client to go? For example if you authenticated you could have a redirect like: redirect('http://myfavoritesite.com/userid=12325&name=Ralph")

Answer (score 0):

add the redirect route

```
app.get('/google/callback/users', function(req, res) {
    return res.json(JSON.stringify( 
           // assume you add the user object after google auth callback
           {user: req.user}
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the authenticated user from the request object, for instance, if you are in the index route:

```
router.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<html>
    <body>
    User data: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}
    </body>
    </html>`); 
});
```

Or, if you are inside the users route:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`<html>
    <body>
    User data: ${JSON.stringify(req.user)}
    </body>
    </html>`); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build a redirection to a client page, you can do the following:

Instead of setting `successRedirect` to a backend URL, set it to a Angular route, then propagate the request to your backend via `XHRHttpRequest` and then return your data to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the data that you want to show in the client-side page such as token expiration time, refresh token, etc, and create a link for your client-side application(`http://<application_root>/route1/:exptime/:reftoken`).

Setup a route handler in your client-side application config.

For example: In AngularJS application-

application config:

```
$routeProvider
        .when('/route1/:exptime/:reftoken', {
            templateUrl: 'route1.html',
            controller: 'RoutingController'
        })
```

RoutingController:

```
module.controller("RoutingController", function ($scope, $routeParams) {
    // Using $routeParams
    $scope.param1 = $routeParams.exptime;
    $scope.param2 = $routeParams.reftoken;
});
```

With this you can get the desired output on the view and also avoid using the templating engine in the nodejs application.